# Slide in menu for android app - that allows user to switch between multiple activities

Tags: android

I have only recently started coding in android(although have had previous exposure to java) a couple of months ago.
 Now I have seen many tutorials about having a slide-in menu(like facebook app) which end user can use to navigate throughout the application already - as well as looking at possible solutions like this one https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu on github.
However, my problem arises that all the solutions work around the basis of changing fragments and not activities. My knowledge to date on android is limited so wanted to know is this even possible?
If so, is there any sample solutions out there that someone could link me to?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What you call a slide-in menu is actually called a navigation drawer in Android. It's become very popular lately.
You can get more information about it's use there: 
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

For implementation guidelines and code sample, go there:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Also, please checkout the design guidelines about what the navigation drawer should be used for in Android, in order to avoid using it for the wrong things:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5COhlbpIbY

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using Android's [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) as it achieves similar results.  As for starting a new activity when you click on a fragment in the navigation menu, you can just override the `onClick()` method for the fragment so that you fire an intent to start the new activity you want.

Comment: Hi Rahin,When creating an activity a corresponding xml layout file is generated with that activity. Would i have to replicate the drawer layout in the xml file of the new activity if i wanted to keep the menu when crossing into a new activity deeper within the application?

Comment: If you're planning on implementing the logic where a new activity is called everytime you click on a navigation drawer fragment, then yes, you'll need to replicate the drawer layout of the new activity.  What I'd recommend doing is following @muslidrikk's advice and watch the video they linked to about navigation drawer design.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the SlidingMenu library, https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu which you have already looked at.

It is extremely easy to setup, and works well with switching activities instead of fragments. It is not quite the same as the official Navigation Drawer, but results in a similar effect. I have implemented it in my app (switching activities).

```
menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setShadowWidth(8);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.8f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setBehindWidth(800);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);
navListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_menu);

final String[] nav = { "Item 1",
        "Item 2",
        "Item 3",
        "Item 4",
        "Item 5"
};

// A list of type RowItem, which essentially just stores the titles of each item
List<RowItem> rowItems;

rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(navPhoto[i], nav[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}

// A custom adapter, for laying out the row item in sliding menu
CustomListViewAdapter listAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
        R.layout.nav_item_layout, rowItems);

navListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
// You can set this onItemClickListener to listen for click events in the nav list
// And open new activities based on that
navListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```